# extract letters by counting them

Tags: csh, counting, letters

I am looking for extracting some of the string by counting the letter from the beginning in csh shell. For example,

set a = "hello 911 is not 91 only"

I want to extract letter from position 8 to 10 which is 911, similar to a(8:10). Similarly, 20 to 21 for 91. How is it possible?

Thanks for your help. 
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csh` does not have string functions. UNIX traditionally uses small and simple programs. Selecting data (columns or words) can be done using (for example) `sed`, `awk` or `cut`. In this case one solution using `cut` would be:

```
% set a = "hello 911 is not 91 only"
% echo $a
hello 911 is not 91 only
% echo $a | cut -c 7-9
911
% echo $a | cut -c 18-19
91
```

Note that your columns are off a bit, 911 is indeed at the 7th to 9th characters.

Or if you want to have the result in a variable:

```
% set a = "hello 911 is not 91 only"
% set b = `echo $a | cut -c 7-9`
% set c = `echo $a | cut -c 18-19`
% echo "I found $b and $c"
I found 911 and 91
```